# Regular Expressions - Select the Second Match

Tags: regex, replace, editpad

I have a txt file with `<i>` and `</i>` between words that I would like to remove using Editpad

For example, I'd like to keep when it's like this:

```
<i>Phrases and words.</i>
```

And I'd like to remove the `</i>` and `<i>` tags inside the phrase, when it's like this:

```
<i>Phrases</i>and<i> words.</i>
<i>Phrases</i>and <i>words.</i>
```

I was trying to do that using regex, but I couldn't do it.

As the tag is followed by space or a word character I could find when the line has the double tag with

```
/ <i>|<\/i> /
```

but this way I can't just press replace for nothing, I have to edit line by line I search.

There's anyway to accomplish that?

### * Edited *

Another example of lines found on the subtitle text

```
<i>- find me on the chamber.</i>
- What? <i>Go. Go, go, go!</i>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule number one: you [can't parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3089519).

That being said, if you know each line follows a certain pattern, you can usually hack something together to work. ;)

If I've understood correctly, it looks like you can simply remove all `<i>` and `</i>` that aren't either at the beginning or end of the lines. In that case, one method you could try is the following regex:

```
(?<=.)\<\/?i\>(?=.)
```

This will match the tags, with a lookahead and behind to make sure  that we aren't at the end/start of a line (by checking if another character exists in front/behind. (Note that typically matched characters in a lookahead/behind won't be replaced when you search/replace.)

Disclaimer: this works on [regex101](https://regex101.com/), but notepad++ may have some differences to the pcre regex style.

### update to work with Editpad

EDIT: since this question is actually wanting to know how to do this in Editpad, below is a modified alternative:

Try searching for the regex: `(.)\<\/?i\>(.)`. This will match (and capture) exactly one character before and after the `<i>` tags.

When replacing, use [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to replace the entire match with the two captured characters - a replacement string of `\1\2` should work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's a subtitle file. Unfortunately it didn't work. I'm using EditPad a similar program to Notepad++. I believe the regex from these programs are the javascript regex style

Comment: @Comentarist why did you tag your question with `notepad++` then? Two alternatives: use notepad++ or another more powerful editor to do this particular operation, or modify this regex to work with javascript style regex (regex101 says lookbehinds aren't in js regex)

Comment: I tagged because a code that work on notepad++ might work on my too, which is not the case. Can you modify this regex to work with javascript style? If I could, I would.

Comment: It didn't work properly, but thank you. I believe I can do the job this way almost as manually. Sometimes it is matching 2 captured characters before </i> and the backreference \1\2 replacement eats 1 letter. By my fault I had to change the code to `[^- ](.)\<\/?i\>(.)` because the dialogue lines with `- <i>Text...` was matching

Comment: @Comentarist If you are adding the `[^- ]` part to the start, you could put that within the first parentheses to make `([^- ].)...`, so it won't eat that first character.